# Why are the bash -n and -z test operators not inverses for $@

Tags: bash, operators

```
function wtf() {
  echo "\$*='$*'"
  echo "\$@='$@'"
  echo "\$@='"$@"'"
  echo "\$@='""$@""'"
  if [ -n "$*" ]; then echo " [ -n \$* ]"; else echo "![ -n \$* ]"; fi
  if [ -z "$*" ]; then echo " [ -z \$* ]"; else echo "![ -z \$* ]"; fi
  if [ -n "$@" ]; then echo " [ -n \$@ ]"; else echo "![ -n \$@ ]"; fi
  if [ -z "$@" ]; then echo " [ -z \$@ ]"; else echo "![ -z \$@ ]"; fi
}

wtf
```

produces

> ```
> $*=''
> $@=''
> $@=''
> $@=''
> ![ -n $* ]
>  [ -z $* ]
>  [ -n $@ ]
>  [ -z $@ ]
> ```

though it seems to me that `[-n $@]` should be false because [7.3 Other Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) indicates that `[ -n "$X" ]` should be the inverse of `[ -z "$X" ]` for all `$X`.

> ## `-z`
>
> string is null, that is, has zero length
>
> ```
> String=''   # Zero-length ("null") string variable.
>
> if [ -z "$String" ]
> then
>   echo "\$String is null."
> else
>   echo "\$String is NOT null."
> fi     # $String is null.
> ```
>
> ## `-n`
>
> string is not null.
>
> The `-n` test requires that the string be quoted within the test brackets. Using an unquoted string with `! -z`, or even just the unquoted string alone within test brackets (see Example 7-6) normally works, however, this is an unsafe practice. Always quote a tested string. [1]

I know `$@` is special but I did not know it was special enough to violate boolean negation.  What is happening here?

---

```
$ bash -version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.2.42(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.2.0)
```

---

The actual numeric exit codes are all `1` or `0` as per

```
$ [ -n "$@" ]; echo "$?"
0
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When `$@` is empty, `"$@"` doesn't expand to an empty string; it is removed altogether. So your test is not

```
[ -n "" ]
```

but rather

```
[ -n ]
```

Now `-n` isn't an operator, but just a non-empty string, which always tests as true.

Comment: Ok.  So `$@` is some lexical syntactic sugar which non-obviously triggers the "The `-n` test requires that the string be quoted" caveat.

Comment: That's why I stick to `[[` in bash.

Comment: @choroba: I was just verifying that `[[...]]` is smart enough to see that `-n` is missing its argument.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I should stop being a dinosaur and just assume that `[[...]]` will be available when I write a script unless I have reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: @chepner: I'd guess it is not missing it. `[[ -n ]]` is a syntax error.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Just use `#!/bin/bash` in the shebang instead of `#!/bin/sh` and you are safe :)

Comment: It's probably wrong to use `"$@"` in this context in the first place. If there are multiple arguments, it will expand to `[[ -n "arg1" "arg2" ]]`, which is invalid.

Comment: @choroba, strangely `[[ -n "$@" ]]` is not a syntax error even when argc is 0.

Comment: @choroba, I did use `#!/bin/bash` though left that detail out of my example input :)

Answer (score 4):

`"$@"` doesn't do what you expect. It's not a different form of `"$*"`, it expands to the quoted list of arguments passed to the current script.

If there are no arguments, it expands to nothing. If there are two arguments `a` and `b c`, then it expands to `"a" "b c"` (i.e. it preserves whitespace in arguments) while `"$*"` expands to `"a b c"` and `$*` would expand to `a b c` (three words).